# Extract American Wheat Specialty Grain recommendations?

Tags: extract-brewing, specialty-grains, wheat-beer

I'm planning on brewing an American Wheat Ale with extract soon and looking for advice on specialty grains. I'm reading suggestions to not use any specialty grains, but I thought I'd see if anyone had luck adding any.

My recipe with look something like this:

4lbs Wheat DME

2lbs Light LME

1oz Cascade

1oz Centennial

Wyeast 1056

Probably ferment it around 64F in the hope of a fruity addition from the yeast.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you've got a nice beer here that will be really drinkable for the season when it's ready in a few weeks. Really, there isn't a need for specialty grains unless you want to just add them out of habit. In that case you could use a pound of some light 2 row and a pound of american wheat. But I don't think it's going to really effect your profile/abv/color very much. I'd avoid any crystal malts which I think will dent the drinkability of this beer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest steeping a pound of Carapils. It will improve the grainy flavors that you just can’t get from extract alone, and since it is already converted (caramel/crystal malt), no mashing is necessary.

Alternatively or eventually, you may want to move towards a partial mash brewing process to further enhance malt flavors, including those you can get from base malts.

Comment: Would carafoam or maltodextrin do something similar?

Comment: Carafoam, yes. Maltodextrin, no.